# Rearrange rows in slick grid

Tags: jquery-animate, slickgrid

We have requirement to rearrange slick grid rows.

I have up/down icon in each row, I want to achieve animation like, clicking 'up' icon should move rows up by '1' position, but cursor must not shift its focus from current row. And other rows should rearrange their position in respect to the 'clicked row'.

Please suggest solution to this problem. Thanks

Comment: The question needs more detail. When you click on the icon, how many rows does the view move up? When you say 'the cursor must not shift its focus', do you mean that it stays in the same spot on the screen, which implies that a different row now has the focus?

Comment: Added few more details in question. 

So, basically i want to achieve that, not to move clicked rows on UI but other rows should be rearranged on UI. 

For example:  If i clicked 'up' button for 3rd row on the UI, row 2 should move down, And cursor position should not be shifted from row 3 'Up' button.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want a sorting function. The method I'd choose depends a bit on how the back end database stores the sort order, if you are persisting to a database.
If you are not persisting the data,

- create an extra column SortOrder, sort by whatever other columns you want to be the default sort order and set SortOrder to 1, 2, 3, ... , n
- create the buttons using a formatter, and make the up/down buttons call javascript that

  - switches the sort number with the row before/after
  - resorts and rerenders the grid
  - sets focus (if necessary) to the desired row using grid.setActiveCell() and grid.focus()

Pesonally, I store SortOrder as an *int* database column, and set it to all zeroes initially so that secondary default sort columns can be used if no custom sort is desired. However the sort index algorithm is significantly more complex.